How to evaluate $\displaystyle\int{e^x\tan^{-1}{(e^x)}\left( \ln((2\sinh{x})^2 + 4)\right)dx}+ \int{e^x \cot^{-1}{(e^{-x})}(2x + 2)}dx$

$$\int{e^x\tan^{-1}{(e^x)}\left( \ln((2\sinh{x})^2  + 4)\right)dx}+ \int{e^x \cot^{-1}{(e^{-x})}(2x + 2)}dx$$

Context: This is one of the challenging integrals in my workbook. It falls under a summary exercise which covers evaluating integrals with more than $1$ type of function (ie. trig and exp combined as above), using methods like IBP, $u$-sub, manipulating identities of exp/trig.
As the exponential is outside, I initially substituted $t = e^x, dt = e^xdx$ and $2\sinh{x} = t - 1/t$. And so the integral becomes
$$\int{\tan^{-1}{t}\cdot\left( \ln(t - 1/t)^2 + 4\right)}dt + \int{\cot^{-1}{1/t}\cdot (2\ln{t} + 2)}dt$$
Here is where I am stuck. I tried IBP on both integrals. (Define the two integrals as $I_1$ and $I_2$ respectively).

$I_1$

$$u = \ln{(t - 1/t)^2 + 4}\,,\quad du = \frac{4t}{1 + t^2} - \frac{2}{t}dt
\\dv = \tan^{-1}{t}\,dt,\quad v = t\tan^{-1}{t} - \frac{\ln{(t^2 + 1)}}{2}
\\\therefore \text{$u\cdot v$ is clear. But after} \int{v\cdot du} = \int{\left(t\tan^{-1}{t} - \frac{\ln{(t^2 + 1)}}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{4t}{1 + t^2} - \frac{2}{t}\right)}dt \\\text{I am unable to solve} \int{\frac{\ln{(t^2 + 1)}}{t}}dt \text{ as there is no obvious substitution; $d[t^2 + 1] = 2t\cdot dt$ does not simplfy}$$

$I_2$

$$u = 2\ln{t} + 2\,,\quad du = \frac{2}{t}dt
\\dv = \cot^{-1}{t}\,dt,\quad v = -t\tan^{-1}{t} + \frac{\ln{(t^2 + 1)}}{2} + \frac{\pi t}{2}
\\\text{ And so yet again after } \int{v\cdot du}\,, \text{ I am left with } \int{\frac{\ln{(t^2 + 1)}}{t}}dt$$
So overall I need help with $\displaystyle\int{\frac{\ln{(t^2 + 1)}}{t}}dt$. Even so, I included the entire question as I am skeptical that IBP is the only method, because the answer in the textbook:

 $$I_1 + I_2 = -\frac{\ln^2{(e^{2x} + 1)}}{2} + 2e^x\tan^{-1}{(e^x)}\cdot\ln{(e^{2x} + 1)} + \ln{(e^{2x} + 1)} + 2\left(\tan^{-1}{e^x}\right)^2 - 2e^x\tan^{-1}{(e^x)} + C$$


There are terms like $\pi t$ after $I_2$; $\displaystyle\int{v \cdot du} = \dots \int{\frac{2}{t} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2t}}dt$ that do not exist in the answer.

Perhaps I am targeting the integrals with IBP incorrectly.

Something may have gone wrong for $\int t^{-1}\log(1+t^2),dt$ leads to a polylogarithm. Read, not an elementary function. The best hit ApproachZero gave to me is about a definite integral calculated on AOPS.

For your request
$$K=\int{\frac{\log{(t^2 + 1)}}{t}}\,dt$$ let $t=\sqrt z$
$$K=\frac 12 \int \frac{\log (z+1)}{ z}\,dz=-\frac 12\text{Li}_2(-z)=-\frac{1}{2}\text{Li}_2\left(-t^2\right)$$ which is a polylogarithm.
Back to the expression in title
If you consider the expression as a whole, after $x=\log(t)$, the total integrand is just
$$2 \tan ^{-1}(t)\,\left(1+\log\left(t^2+1\right)\right)$$ One integration by parts give
$$\int \tan ^{-1}(t)\,dt=t \tan ^{-1}(t)-\frac{1}{2} \log   \left(t^2+1\right)$$ For the second one
$$\int \tan ^{-1}(t)\,\log\left(t^2+1\right)\,dt$$ use integration by parts with $u=\log(t^2+1)$ and you will not see any  polylogarithm.
The question, as written in title, is a red herring !

Combining the integrals is as simple but brilliant! Thank you!
